# Make function return predictable values for testing purposes

Tags: python, django, pytest

I need a function to return predictable values when running tests.
For example, I have a function `get_usd_rates()`, which is loading USD forex rates from some API.

So far when I was using it inside any other function I was passing rates as an optional argument for testing purposes only. Seems hacky, but it worked. Like this:

```py
def some_other_function(rates=None):
    if rates is None:
        rates = get_usd_rates()

    # do something with rates
```

But now I am facing a situation where I can't pass extra argument to a function (private class method for django model, which is called on model field change).

Is there a way to make `get_usd_rates()` function aware that test is running and always return some predefined value without noticeable performance impact in this case?
Or what is the best way to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is `mock` the methods. This is a module present in the unittest module. Try using `mock.patch`:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('path.to.get_usd_rates')
def your_test_function(mock_get_usd_rates):
    mock_get_usd_rates.return_value = "Some predefined value"
    # Rest of your test (Anywhere that get_usd_rates is used will now automaticlly use mock_get_usd_rates)
```

What happens here is that `mock.patch` will replace your function get_usd_rates with a mock on which you set what you want the return value to be. There are various ways to do this other than a decorator (context manager for one, etc.) Reference: [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html)